# Sync a custom calendar in Outlook

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, activesync

We're working on a project where we need to be able to (2 way) sync an employee's holiday requests (submitted using a web application) in his Outlook application. Are there any standard ways to do this or interesting links to read?

Do we have to create a new email address for each of the employees? Or are there better options?

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way of doing that. You would need to write your custom code that syncs the two.